# How to run a Bash script that calls a Python script from any location?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a Python script, say `myscript.py`, that uses relative module imports, ie `from .. import module1`, where my project layout is as follows:

```
project
 + outer_module
   - __init__.py
   - module1.py
   + inner_module
     - __init__.py
     - myscript.py
     - myscript.sh
```

And I have a Bash script, say `myscript.sh`, which is a wrapper for my python script, shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m outer_module.inner_module.myscript $@
```

This works to execute `myscript.py` and forwards the arguments to my script as desired, but it only works when I call `./outer_module/inner_module/myscript.sh` from within the `project` directory shown above.

How can I make this script work from anywhere? For example, how can I make this work for a call like `bash /root/to/my/project/outer_module/inner_module/myscript.sh`?

Here are my attempts:

When executing `myscript.sh` from anywhere else, I get the error: `No module named outer_module.inner_module`. Then I tried another approach to execute the bash script from anywhere, by replacing `myscript.sh` with:

```
#!/bin/bash
scriptdir=`dirname "$BASH_SOURCE"`
python $scriptdir/myscript.py $@
```

When I execute `myscript.sh` as shown above, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./inner_module/myscript.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .. import module1
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Which is due to the relative import on the first line in `myscript.py`, as mentioned earlier, which is `from .. import module1`.

Comment: try: `(cd $scriptdir && python ./devicelist.py $@)`

Comment: Your working directory has to be the directory that `outer_module` is in, not in `outer_module` itself; otherwise `outer_module` isn't a package (hence the exception). (It's hard to be too precise since you seem to have switched names for everything halfway through the question, but if you're inside `inner_module`, it's the same problem.)

Comment: Or, alternatively, you just need to not be in _any_ of those directories, and set `PYTHONPATH=<the directory that outer_module is in>` before running the script.

Comment: Also, if you're normally running the script with `-m`, better to have your launcher also use `-m`; there's no reason to try to debug the differences between running it as a `-m` module vs. running it as a script if you don't actually want any of those differences.

Comment: Finally, is there a reason you're not just using `setuptools` to create a trivial installer? Then you could do an in-place build that would build a wrapper for you to use in your source tree, or a normal install that would put the project into site-packages and build a wrapper for you in your bin or scripts directory, and either way, it takes care of all the mess for you.

Comment: To get help easier, please create a small directory tree (possibly on Github) containing all the relevant absolute and relative imports, and then specify a couple of command-line invocations that should work. At the current state your question is to vague to be answered and researched easily.

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says:

```
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

The solution to this is to create a package, and have your script execute with that package in its path.

You already have a package, as you have the `__init__.py` files in those directories; but you only have that package in your path when you are calling it from the project directory, as you mentioned; that's because `.` is in your Python path by default.

To fix this, just add the project directory to your Python path, and then invoke it with `python -m outer_module.inner_module.myscript`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/../..
python -m outer_module.inner_module.myscript $@
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the path to the outer module's parent directory in the `PYTHONPATH` environmental variable, then you can use the same command you used in the first script from anywhere.

The `PYTHONPATH` is where python searches for any modules you try to import:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:PATH/TO/MODULE/PARENTDIR
python -m outer_module.inner_module.myscript $@
```